# Conditional to limit .Net webservice results

Tags: asp.net, json, linq, web-services, sql-server-2008

I'm not sure if this is the right way but I have a web service that returns json. Now I wanted to set a conditional to omit rows returned that have a value of false in cell appearInShowcase. Most of the code is pretty straight forward what it does but the cell that has a true false value is appearInShowcase which is in a table photo. In the ms sql database the appearInShowcase is of type ntext.

```
    public List<wsGalleryPhotos> GetGalleryPhotos(int collectionID)
    {
       photoDataContext dc = new photoDataContext();

        List<wsGalleryPhotos> results = new List<wsGalleryPhotos>();
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

        foreach (photo photo in dc.photos.Where(s => s.collectionID == collectionID)) 
        {
            if(photo.appearInShowcase == "true")
            {
            results.Add(new wsGalleryPhotos()
            {   

                photoID = photo.photoID,
                collectionID = Convert.ToInt32(photo.collectionID),
                name = photo.name,
                description = photo.description,
                filepath = photo.filepath,
                thumbnail = photo.thumbnail


            }); 
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you do this?

Comment: do you want to omit the rows at the client side (HTML)? or at the server side (webservice)?

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Comment: Hey Preet, I get json back but its everything from the table. Everything I try to get some sort of a condition to be met is being ignored. My goal here is to make the webservice smart enough to limit the return based off that table cell.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a condition, you should do it like this:

```
public List<wsGalleryPhotos> GetGalleryPhotos(int collectionID)
    {
       photoDataContext dc = new photoDataContext();

        List<wsGalleryPhotos> results = new List<wsGalleryPhotos>();
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

        results = dc.photos.Where(s => s.collectionID == collectionID && s.appearInShowcase == "true")
                           .Select(s => new wsGalleryPhotos
                            {       
                                 photoID = s.photoID,
                                 collectionID = collectionID,
                                 name = s.name,
                                 description = s.description,
                                 filepath = s.filepath,
                                 thumbnail = s.thumbnail  
                             }).ToList();

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Tim but I'm still getting the entire table returned as if the condition isn't there.

Comment: The wsGalleryPhotos is super simple too. Its just a bunch of getter setters.